# How do I add an HTML code to my website so that when people click it, it opens a WhatsApp conversation with me?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

How do I add an HTML code to my website so that when people click it, it opens a WhatsApp conversation with me?

What I am trying to do is add a clickable link to my website so that potential customers can click it (while on their phone) to open a conversation with me. So far what I have is:

```
<a href="intent://send/+316xxxxxxxxx#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">Text</a>
```

Where `+316xxxxxx` is my phone number. However, this only appears to work for people that already have me as a contact and I am not sure it works for iOS. I've reached the limit of what I can do with my very limited HTML knowledge and I can't find any good info on Google, any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In according to [this article](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251) from WhatsApp FAQ, you may be able to add a link using a URL like this:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=316...">Text</a>
```

I've just tested on iOS 10.3 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about `App Indexing`.

Google has its own `SDK` for this.
[Google App Indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/?hl=en)

And yes you can do this in iOS also but the iOS version must be > 9.
[iOS App Indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app)

Comment: Thanks for replaying. by visiting this link http://www.balcad24.com/wia via mobile you can see what i mean thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HTML code, there are a lot free plugins that allow you to easily add a WhatsApp click-to-chat link with to need to write an HTML code.

Between those, I would suggest you to try:

- Callbell
- WidgetWhats
- WhatsHelp

I recently wrote an article about [how to install the three of them on a website.](https://www.callbell.eu/en/free-plugins-install-whatsapp-website/)

Hope that helps :)